# tile file names different between tiles generated with Mobac and loaded from Internet?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I want to use offline tiles in an Android app using OSMDROID to avoid downloading via Internet. According to several examples here I started to use Mobac for creating tiles of a certain area in OSM MapQuest format. I also folllowed the instruction to generate jpg-format instead of png. The zip-file was generated too succesfully, but the tiles are not displayed in my app. I also checked the folder structure and I also modified the path "MapQuest" to "MapquestOSM", but all experiments were not successful.

The tilesource in my code is set to MAPQUESTOSM and all works fine, when I load the tiles from the Internet, but when I try to read it from my phone-directoy, nothing is displayed.

What I have seen is that on my phone the downloaded tiles have the file name ".jpg.tile", but Mobac generates ".jpg. I extracted the zip file and when I change the file name also to .jpg.tile, then the changed tiles becomes displayed (only the changed ones!). I have not found any issue related to this file name difference!

In my code I use from examples the setTileSource (works for Internet loading):

```
mv = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mv.setUseDataConnection(false);
mv.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
```

on my Samsung J5 the tiles are loaded from Internet into directory /osmdroid/tiles///.jpg.tile

Has there been a change in the file names or what could be wrong. Nobody seemed to have this problem in the past?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior with downloaded tiles vs tile archives produced by mobac or some other tool is expected (extra file extension in the /sdcard/osmdroid/tiles folder).

If you putting a mobac produced archive to a device for osmdroid, put it in /sdcard/osmdroid/

within the archive (assuming zip here) the path in the zip should be
{source}/z/x/y.extension.

The "source" part is what you osmdroid that the source is. It must match exactly or else the tiles will not be loaded.

See the wiki for more info

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles

Comment: Thank you for your answer, spy, I did not found these infos. So this means, that I have to take care on myself for the correct file extension (I do not mean ".png" or ".jpg", I mean the extension ".jpg.tile"), right?